# I Have a problem running the same Angular project on two different computers

Tags: angular, svn

We have an angular project that until now only one developer worked on. 
Lately, a new developer joined the team, and now both developers should work on the same project. 
First of all, we have a problem running the project on the new computer, here I wanted some help to understand what is the problem. 
And anyway, I would love to get some tips for teamwork in angular projects, for example, arranging the source control (we work with svn, not git), angular upgrade policy. and any other helpful tips.

The problem we get on the new computer is the following: 
`Cannot GET /`ng

in the browser console I get the following error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

I run the command **ng serve -o** at the root of my project.

The following is the compilation output for **ng serve -o**

```
0% compiling
Compiling @angular/core : es2015 as esm2015
10% building 3/3 modules 0 activei ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:4200/webpack-dev-server/
i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /
i ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to //index.html

chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 2.01 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 154 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.15 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {scripts} scripts.js, scripts.js.map (scripts) 7.53 MB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 2.27 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 340 kB [initial] [rendered]
Date: 2020-04-26T17:21:45.905Z - Hash: 642489da10cb01318687 - Time: 73590ms

ERROR in The target entry-point "@fullcalendar/angular" has missing dependencies:
 - @fullcalendar/core/types/input-types
 - @fullcalendar/core/datelib/env
 - @fullcalendar/core/datelib/duration
 - @fullcalendar/core/datelib/formatting
 - @fullcalendar/core/datelib/date-range
 - @fullcalendar/core/datelib/locale
 - @fullcalendar/core/validation
 - @fullcalendar/core/structs/event-source

** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
i ｢wdm｣: Compiling...
i ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /

Date: 2020-04-26T17:21:54.537Z - Hash: 642489da10cb01318687
6 unchanged chunks

Time: 6253ms

ERROR in The target entry-point "@fullcalendar/angular" has missing dependencies:
 - @fullcalendar/core/types/input-types
 - @fullcalendar/core/datelib/env
 - @fullcalendar/core/datelib/duration
 - @fullcalendar/core/datelib/formatting
 - @fullcalendar/core/datelib/date-range
 - @fullcalendar/core/datelib/locale
 - @fullcalendar/core/validation
 - @fullcalendar/core/structs/event-source

i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

the result of **ng --version** is the following:

```
Angular CLI: 9.1.3
Node: 10.16.3
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 9.1.3
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.901.3
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.803.25
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.803.25
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.803.25
@angular-devkit/core              9.1.3
@angular-devkit/schematics        9.1.3
@ngtools/webpack                  8.3.25
@schematics/angular               9.1.3
@schematics/update                0.901.3
rxjs                              6.5.3
typescript                        3.8.3
webpack                           4.39.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the same package-lock and package JSON in both the system run an npm install after deleting the previously created node module folder as I could see

ERROR in The target entry-point "@fullcalendar/angular" has missing dependencies:
 - @fullcalendar/core/types/input-types
 - @fullcalendar/core/datelib/env
 - @fullcalendar/core/datelib/duration
 - @fullcalendar/core/datelib/formatting
 - @fullcalendar/core/datelib/date-range
 - @fullcalendar/core/datelib/locale
 - @fullcalendar/core/validation
 - @fullcalendar/core/structs/event-source

full calendar misses few dependencies. Cannot GET / will be shown if there is any error in the compiling of dependencies.

Comment: Thanks, It works. I didn't notice that the package-lock and package files weren't identical.  But, This means that the next angular update will be with problems???

Comment: Ideally when you are in project where multiple people work package versions are important. When you upgrade angular or any other, package jsons should be made same across the working environment systems. That's how npm maintains correct version of project dependencies.